# Задача "Самое частое слово"

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

> Дан текст. Выведите слово, которое в этом тексте встречается чаще всего. Если таких слов несколько, выведите то, которое меньше в лексикографическом порядке.

Моя реализация:

```
import sys

d = {}
text = sys.stdin.read()
myLine = [a for b in text.split('\n') for a in b.split()]
for word in myLine:
    d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1
for i in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0])):
    if i[1] == max(d.values()):
        print(i[0])
        break
```

Проверяющая система утверждает, что можно сделать, чтобы работало быстрее. 
Каким образом?

Comment: Counter разрешён к использованию?

Comment: @insolor в условии на эту тему нет оговорки

Comment: Откуда вы берете задачки?

Comment: Хотя в общем-то Counter по сути это тот же словарь, не факт что будет быстрее. Что можно ускорить: 0-не нужно создавать список слов `myLine`, можно сделать генератор (круглые скобки вместо квадратных) 1-максимальное количество находить только один раз вне цикла. 2-не сортировать весь список слов, а найти максимально частые, и из них выбрать минимальное (список частых слов короче полного списка, нахождение минимума экспоненциально быстрее сортировки).

Comment: @danilshik курсы на курсере, степике. там столько всякого полезного с автоматической проверкой - просто настоящий Клондайк!

Comment: @insolor большое спасибо!

Comment: Бесплатный курс?

Comment: @danilshik да! но если нужен сертификат, можно заплатить что-то около 2000 всего лишь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вот мой, немного извращенный, вариант:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

d = Counter(re.sub(r'\W' ,' ', text).split())
res = min(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))[0]
```

вместо `Counter` можно воспользоваться `defaultdict`:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for word in re.sub(r'\W' ,' ', text).split():
    d[word] += 1

res = min(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))[0]
print(res)
```

Пример:

```
In [170]: d
Out[170]:
defaultdict(int,
            {'Дан': 1,
             'текст': 1,
             'Выведите': 1,
             'слово': 1,
             'которое': 2,
             'в': 2,
             'этом': 1,
             'тексте': 1,
             'встречается': 1,
             'чаще': 1,
             'всего': 1,
             'Если': 1,
             'таких': 1,
             'слов': 1,
             'несколько': 1,
             'выведите': 1,
             'то': 1,
             'меньше': 1,
             'лексикографическом': 1,
             'порядке': 1})
```

для наглядности можно остортировать:

```
In [171]: sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
Out[171]:
[('в', 2),
 ('которое', 2),
 ('Выведите', 1),
 ('Дан', 1),
 ('Если', 1),
 ('всего', 1),
 ('встречается', 1),
 ('выведите', 1),
 ('лексикографическом', 1),
 ('меньше', 1),
 ('несколько', 1),
 ('порядке', 1),
 ('слов', 1),
 ('слово', 1),
 ('таких', 1),
 ('текст', 1),
 ('тексте', 1),
 ('то', 1),
 ('чаще', 1),
 ('этом', 1)]

In [180]: min(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
Out[180]: ('в', 2)

In [181]: min(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))[0]
Out[181]: 'в'
```

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @Lazarevna, всегда рад помочь :)

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно научиться понимать, какая сложность стоит за каждой функцией, которую вы используете.

Проблема вашего решения в том, что вы неоправданно усложнили алгоритм до квадратичной сложности. А именно.

```
max(d.values)
```

Чтобы посчитать максимум среди N элементов неупорядоченного списка, нужно линейное время(т.е. время линейно зависит от размера списка).
Вы же делаете это в цикле по всем элементам.  То есть время алгоритма, зависит от количества элементов квадратично(N * N)

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import Counter

text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."""

myLine = text.split()  # split() без аргументов делит по пробельным символам, в том числе и по переносам строк
d = Counter(myLine)  # один проход с подсчетом в словаре - примерно O(n)
max_encounters = max(d.values())  # нахождение максимума - О(n)
most_common_word = min(word for word, count in d.items() if count == max_encounters)  # нахождение минимального из максимально частых слов O(n*m) (m - количество самых частых слов)
print(most_common_word)  # получаем слово "in"
```

Просто список самых частых слов можно получить через `d.most_common()` (без аргументов эквивалентно `sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])`):

> ```
> [('in', 3),
>  ('dolor', 2),
>  ('ut', 2),
>  ('dolore', 2),
>  ('Lorem', 1),
>  ('ipsum', 1),
>  ('sit', 1),
>  ('amet,', 1),
>  ('consectetur', 1),
>  ('adipiscing', 1),
>  ('elit,', 1),
>  ('sed', 1),
>  ('do', 1),
>  ('eiusmod', 1),
>  ('tempor', 1),
>  ('incididunt', 1),
> ...
> ```

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: Решение insolor работает на курсере с изменением ввода на sys.stdin.read().split() Сколько еще мне нужно узнать...